# Reactive forms access nested formgroup field inside formArray

Tags: angular

I am using reactive forms with Angular4. My form:

```
this._form = this._formBuilder.group({
    id: [''],
    name: ['', [Validators.required]],
    type: ['', [DropDownValidator.Validate()]],
    length: ['', [Validators.required]],
    timesPerWeek: ['', [Validators.required]],
    workouts: this._formBuilder.array([
        this._formBuilder.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required],
            description: ['', Validators.required]
        })
    ])
});
```

I am then using generic validation component which uses following function:

```
// returns false if no error, returns true if error
public IsFieldInvalid(form: FormGroup, field: string, errorType: string){
    return form.get(field).hasError(errorType) && form.get(field).dirty;// || form.get(field).hasError(errorType) && form.get(field).pristine && this.IsControlType(form, field, 'radio');
}
```

In html I then pass form and field via shared component for high level 'name':

```
      <app-field-error-display [displayError]="formValidationService.IsFieldInvalid(_form,'name','required')" errorMsg="Field is required"></app-field-error-display>
```

As you can see for first name, I have no issue I just pass field name 'name'.

How can I access nested 'name' inside of workouts array for validation to be accepted inside IsFieldInvalid function as 'field:string' parameter? I tried multiple things but with errors.

I tried this with errors:

```
  <app-field-error-display [displayError]="formValidationService.IsFieldInvalid(_form,'_form.controls.workouts.controls[i].controls.name','required')" errorMsg="Field is required"></app-field-error-display>
```

Comment: What was the error description? Also I assume that in your html you are correctly naming your `formGroup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get()` function](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L507) may receive array of strings or numbers or just a string, which suits your case. Then, [`_find()` function](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L37) will just *split* it using `.` (period) delimiter. Your path contains `workouts` form array which contains a single form group with index 0, which has form controls `name` and `description`.

So just try to pass `workouts.0.name` for name or `workouts.0.description` paths:

```
<app-field-error-display [displayError]="formValidationService.IsFieldInvalid(_form, 'workouts.0.name', 'required')" 
                         errorMsg="Field is required"></app-field-error-display>
```

Comment: i think this is the way, since i am getting workouts.0.name inside. how would i use index instead of 0? workouts.[i].name doesn't work

Comment: then make your `IsFieldInvalid()` function to receive an array of strings as second parameter: public IsFieldInvalid(form: FormGroup, field: Array<string>|string, errorType: string). This way you can pass an array: `['workouts', i, 'name']`